# Do Alchemists need sleep before preparing Extracts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I can't find anything saying the Alchemist needs rest to replenish his capacity to make Extracts. But then again, she's not a caster, so it'd make sense.

I'd just like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

> An alchemist can create only a certain number of extracts of each level **per day**.
>
> An extract, once created, remains potent for **1 day** before losing its magic, so an alchemist must re-prepare his extracts every day.
>
> Mixing an extract takes 1 minute of work — **most** alchemists prepare many extracts **at the start of the day** or just before going on an adventure, but it's not uncommon for an alchemist to keep some (or even all) of his **daily extract slots** open so that he can prepare extracts in the field as needed.

If no rest is needed, this also begs the question of "when does the day start?" Is it simply midnight?

Comment: So how are you bypassing the need to rest? Large amounts of coffee?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a thorough search, I've determined that no, there is no requirement for the Alchemist to rest to prepare extracts.

If you don't need to sleep, the day begins when you feel like it! Generally what you consider most convenient, be it midnight, mid-afternoon, dusk, or when your allies begin prepping for adventure.

Comment: I'll assume the 24 hours timer starts at preparation rather than use, as opposed to how other casters work?

Comment: @leokhorn No spellcaster has a “twenty-four hour timer,” and it’s certainly not on hold until you first use a spell. Arcane spellcasters prepare spells after 8 hours of sleep, regardless of how long it has been since the last time they prepared or cast a spell (though any spells cast in the last 8 hours are unavailable), while divine spellcasters simply pray for spells at a specific time of day, each day. There isn’t a timer, it’s just that twenty-four hours tends to elapse between a specific time in one day and the same time the next day.

Comment: As a note, for my own campaign I've decided to just relax with these rules and only care about them if they bring interesting issues. I will warn the players if I plan to make it count, so they don't plan unknowingly.